React-grid-layout + React-flow ( minimap usage with react-grid-layout )
I have layout that is build using react-grid-layout, and I want to add minimap that has simmilar functinality as react-flow minimap, but I cant find a way how they can work together, or how to create same functinality using another lib. ( This preview should be copy of original div )
I tried to use react-flow but it didnt helped

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
